# Не изменяется содержимое поля textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

В цикле создаю кнопки и привязываю обработчик 'click' с помощью инструментов jQuery:

```
for(var i = 0; i < UserFiles.length; i++)
{
    var newButton = $('<label class="btn btn-primary files">File' + (i + 1) + '</label>');
    newButton.append('<input type="radio">');
    newButton.bind('click', ButtonFileClick);
    $('#Buttons').append(newButton);
}
```

Нажатие каждой кнопки удаляет текст в 'textarea' и записывает новый(какой именно определяет название кнопки(оно берется в первой строке)):

```
var num = $(this).text().slice(4,5) - 1;
$('#TextCode').empty()
$('#TextCode').html(UserFiles[num]['content']);
selectedFile = num;
```

Пока кнопки бездействуют вызывается событие 'input' у 'textarea':

```
$('#TextCode').on('input', function () {
    if(selectedFile == undefined)
    {
        $('#createFile').click();
    }
    var change = $(this).val();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "request.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: ({command: "UpdateFile", id_file: UserFiles[selectedFile]['id'], content: change }),
            dataType: "html",
        });
    },200);
});
```

После чего возникает сама проблема. Событие нажатия кнопки перестают влиять на 'textarea'. Вся реализация блевотно-костыльная, было бы очень приятно увидеть вариант адекватнее

Comment: "Пока кнопки бездействуют вызывается событие 'input' у 'textarea':" - кем вызывается? Что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @Igor я хотел реализовать сохранение содержимого "textarea" путем отправки на сервер каждый раз когда вызывается событие "input". Идея сверх гениальная спорить не буду, но проблема заключается в том что при отправке содержимого я теряю возможность манипулировать им(содержимым). Проблему решил все еще супер гениальной, удалением блока "textarea" и вставке нового на его место.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TextCode').val(UserFiles[num]['content']);
```